# Java serializable HashMap to ByteArray for creating a blob

Tags: java

When I tried it, I get this message error:

java.io.NotSerializableException:

```
  private HashMap<String, XlsData> myMap= new HashMap<String, XlsData>();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out;
                try {
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(bObj);
                if(myMap != null){
                out.writeObject(myMap);
                out.close();
                bObj.close();
                byte[] byteOut = bObj.toByteArray();
              }
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    public class XlsData implements Serializable {

            private String dataA;
            private String dataB;

            public String getDataA() {
                return dataA;
            }
            public void setDataA(String dataA) {
                this.dataA= dataA;
            }
            public String getDataB() {
                return dataB;
            }
            public void setDataB(String dataB) {
                this.dataB= dataB;
            }
}
```

What it's necessary to works fine? As it's possible see my inner class implements a serializabe class too.

Comment: Show the rest of your exception.  It's most likely telling you exactly which object in your map is not serializable.

Comment: show the `myMap` defination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `XlsData` class needs to be a static inner class:

```
public static class XlsData implements Serializable {
```

Because it is not static, it behaves like a non-static field:  it can only exist as part of an instance of the outer class.  When you serialize an instance of a non-static inner class, you are also serializing the enclosing outer class object, which I'm guessing is not serializable (or one or more of its fields is not serializable).

Comment: What code?  The original question doesn't show the outer class.  Did you run it with an outer class that isn't serializable?

Comment: I ran that code in a non-serializable outer class and got a NotSerializableException.  Are you sure you made XlsData an inner class?  If you add `System.out.println(XlsData.class);` to your code, what do you see?

Comment: You are serializing an empty map.  Put at least one entry into the map, and see if it still serializes successfully.

Comment: My outer class didn't define an implements Serializable. After change to Serializable is working now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, simply one of the elements of you're map isn't serializable. Or an element of the map holds a member that is neither serializable nor transient. Just look through the map and you should find the answer.